# could we use the verb "poke" without an agent who caused it?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

> **[poke](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/poke)** [intransitive, transitive] to quickly push your finger or some other pointed object into something or someone
>
> **poke somebody/something with something**
>
> Andy poked the fish with his finger to see if it was still alive.
>
> **poke somebody in the eye/arm/ribs etc**
>
> Be careful with that umbrella or you’ll poke someone in the eye.
>
> **poke at**
>
> He was poking at the dust with a stick, making little patterns.

---

Let's say, there is a stick emerges from a ground & a kid is playing near there as showed in this picture.

[image]

Could we say "**Watch out for the stick! it (the stick) may poke into your eyes**"?

However, according to the above definition, the verb "**poke**" can only be used if a person pokes the stick into someone's eyes. The stick can not poke by itself.

Answer (score -2):

According to this definition [poke someone in something](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/poke+you+in) we can easily say:

- Watch out for that stick. It may poke you in the eye.

And it will be grammatically correct.

But in my opinion that sounds weird since I seem to see the stick as a living being.

I would say it like:

- Watch out for that stick. You may get poked in the eye on it by accident. (especially if you fall and hit it) - This is if you aren't wielding it.

Or:

- Watch out for that stick. Try not to get a poke in the eye (poke your eye out) with (or maybe using) it - This is if you are wielding it.

Comment: So to say, why use the verb "poke" anyway? There are much better options.

Comment: how do I say if not using the verb "poke"?

Comment: It is perfectly normal to use verbs like poke, prick, etc, in the way the questioner asks. A protruding thing may poke you in the eye; a sharp thing may prick your finger, water may soak you, ink may blacken your fingers.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yes, I know but depending on how the sentence is constructed sometimes it shows us a very weird image of what is happening.

Comment: That is your subjective judgement.

Comment: OP's sentences, slightly changed, are normal and OK: ""Watch out for the stick! It could poke you in the eye".

Comment: I’m afraid your answer contains grammatical errors and I don't perceive it as useful in any way. In the English language a *person* can *actively* poke you in the eye OR a stick, or some other *inanimate* object, can *passively* poke you in the eye (as you walk past a tree or something). Both are correct uses of the verb. Nothing “weird” here at all.

Comment: @OrbitalAussie That's why I said, that it is only my opinion.

Comment: @OrbitalAussie That is only your subjective opinion!

Comment: SovereignSun - please read the rules and guidelines of this site, and consider whether your comments here are suitable.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I know the rules and guidelines but since you judge my opinion, although it is correct, I can judge yours. I disagree with the downvotes.